# Finding the limit of the recursive sequence $2\sqrt{a_{n-1}}$ where $a_1=5$ (already given that it converges)

Tags: calculus

The question basically has the entire problem. I am not sure how to find the limit of this sequence since it's recursive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $x \mapsto 2\sqrt{x}$ is a continuous function, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2\sqrt{a_n} = 2\sqrt{a}$, now what is $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}$?

Comment: is it just a+1 then?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1} = a$, the limit of a sequence remains the same if you shift all entries by one slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_n = 2\sqrt{a_{n-1}}$ First notice that the limit of $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ are the same. For arguments sake, say this limit is $L$. Then

$a_n = 2\sqrt{a_{n-1}} \Rightarrow a_n^2 = 4a_{n-1}$.

Taking limits across this last gives, $L^2 = 4L \Rightarrow L^2 - 4L = 0 \Rightarrow L(L-4)=0 $.

So either $L = 0$ or $L=4$

Now we want to show that one of these fails, for example we can show that $a_n$ is always greater than 4. We do this by induction on $n$.

$a_1 = 5 > 4$.

Assume $a_n > 4$ for some $n$.  Then

$a_{n+1} = 2\sqrt{a_n} > 2\sqrt{4} = 2\bullet2 =4$.

So by mathematical induction $a_n >4$ for every $n$. Hence $L=4$.

Comment: Just as a note, you also have to show that the limit exists, i.e. that the given sequence is monotone and bounded.

Answer (score 0):

You can also focus on the behaviour of the exponents of 2 and 5: the rule is 
$$x_n = \frac{1}{2}x_{n-1}+1, x_1 = 0 \text{, exponent of 2 at step }n$$
$$y_n = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \text{, exponent of 5 at step }n$$
because at step $n$:

for 2: you take a half of the exponent at step $n-1$ and add 1 (multiplication by 2)

for 5: you take a half of the exponent at step $n-1$, and if $n=1$ you need to have 1.

Now $y_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow +\infty$, so the limit has $0$ as power of $5$, whereas $x_n \rightarrow 2$ as $n \rightarrow +\infty$ ($x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$ have the same limit $x$, which satisfies $x = \frac{x}{2}+1$, so $x=2$), so $2^2\cdot 5^0 = 4$ is the limit of the sequence.